# SSIS Data Flow - How to load identical data into two places?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssis, dts

How can I make identical output from a transformation go to two separate places e.g., an OLE DB destination and a DataReader destination?

**Background:**

I have an existing package that reads data from a text file, does some transformations, and loads the data into a SQL Server table.

Now I'm trying to make the package be callable from a reporting services report (SSRS).  I'm following the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159215.aspx

It says to make my data go into a DataReader destination and then the report will have access to that.  So I want the output of the final transformation to go to both the SQL table, and the DataReader destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `MULTICAST` and send to a "DataReader destination" and "OLEDB destination" in your SSIS package.

When you create your datasets in SSRS, you should use the name of the Output object from your SSIS package.  Your dataset in the report should then populate with fields, data, etc that from the SSIS package.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Multicast step?